# Open message with given message-id from command line in mutt

Tags: email, mutt

I have the value of the `Message ID` header of a particular message in my mutt's inbox and I want to open it with a one shot mutt command, read and close.

Currently, I open mutt, do a  with `~i <the-message-id>`, which lists just one message, and then open it with `o` (My keybinding to open a message).

Is there a way I can create a shell function/script to enable a usage like

```
mutt-open-message <the-message-id>
```

and the message opens up in mutt? I tried playing around with the `-e` option of mutt but couldn't get this functionality working.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that `mutt-open-message` should just output the message and directly return without any user interaction? Or do you want to remote control and already running mutt instance?

Comment: @maxschlepzig, you understand correct. I only need to read the message, whether it be by opening mutt or less or vim whatever pager. Not controlling an already running mutt instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution but this seems to work (using mutt 1.5.20), with  a message ID taken from my inbox in $MSGID:

```
mutt -e "macro index - 'l~i${MSGID}'; push -\n"
```

If you already use the '-' key for something in the index choose a different key instead.

Comment: Slightly modified, to open the message directly: `mutt -e "macro index - 'l~i${MSGID}'; push -\no"`. Ofcourse one would use `\n` in place of the `o` to open the message.

Comment: Ha! Thanks for this answer, I came to know about `push`. A macro isn't really needed actually. Just `mutt -e "push l~i${MSGID}\no"` works just fine

Comment: @ShrikantSharat this gives me the prompt of how to sort. Do I need to change folders to "All mail" first? How do I do that with the command?

Comment: Using `o` I also get the sort prompt. For me the following command opens the message: `mutt -e "push l~i${MSGID}\n<enter>"`